# SQL MAX Query Multiple Columns

Tags: sql

Trying to populate multiple columns based on one MAX value but the grouping returns multiple results. Is there a way I can tell SQL to only pull the values based on the MAX that I want?

Query:

```
Select a.ID, (MAX)a.PayDate, a.AgencyName
From a
Group By a.ID, a.AgencyName
```

What I need is the latest paydate per ID, then I want additional information in reference to that entry such as AgencyName (& more columns I want to add) but because of the grouping - SQL returns the latest paydate for each of the AgencyNames that the person has had - but I only want the AgencyName associated with the record that is Max Paydate for that ID. I know it's the grouping that does this but I am unsure how to proceed - any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select a.ID,a.PayDate, a.AgencyName
From a
where exists (select 1 from a a1 where a1.id = a.id 
  having a.payDate = max(a1.paydate)
Group By a.ID,
```

Comment: Many thanks, It's worked a treat. I see that in the WHERE clause, you open a query to the table itself just to force paydate to be max(paydate). I did have to add AgencyName into the grouping for it to work though but this has saved me a lot of time, was driving me nuts! I marked as answer but cannot (^) due to less than 15rep, I apologise for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a correlated subquery like this:

```
select a.*
from a
where a.paydate = (select max(a2.paydate) from a a2 where a2.id = a.id);
```

Note that this could return multiple rows if an `id` has duplicates on the most recent `paydate`.  An alternative that guarantees one row is `row_number()`:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by paydate desc) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes much more sense now - I was trying via subquery but I was adding this into the SELECT clause instead of the WHERE which is where I think I was going wrong. I managed to get this working now but thanks for your input, I feel more comfortable using this method